# "The most simple Android project has the following build.gradle"

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to learn the gradle build system as it seems to be highly configurable and it is used in Android Studio. I want to always make sure I understand what I'm reading, but this doesn't seem to match up.

The [user guide for the new build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) states that the most simple Android project has the following build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
}
```

When I create a new project in Android Studio I get something more along the lines of:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.eghdk.project"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Now I realize things are moving at an incredibly fast pace for gradle, the gradle plugin for android, build tools, and Android Studio that the documentation will be out of date in some areas. I just wanted to make sure `apply plugin: 'android'` is now obsolete along with why `dependencies{...}` doesn't mention build tools at all. Just trying to wrap my head around gradle and would appreciate some help finding the "most simple Android project has the following build.gradle".

Answer (score 1):

> I just wanted to make sure `apply plugin: 'android'` is now obsolete

Yes. The plugin is now called `com.android.application` for applications and `com.android.library` for libraries.

> [...] along with why dependencies doesn't mention build tools at all

It actually does. The second build.gradle you posted is what Android Studio will generate for the application (or "app") module. If you go to the project's root directory, there will be another build.gradle that is used across all of your project's modules. This is where you will find the `repositories {}` block and the dependencies block with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.Y.Z'`.

As for why the generated one is much longer- The documentation you are looking at with the "simplest" build.gradle is truly showing the bare minimum. You don't **need** to do a lot of the stuff provided in the generated build.gradle such as configuring build types. However, the Android Studio template is designed to provide a basic Gradle build script that provides sane defaults for a lot of the things that most Android developers will want to update in their build script.

You don't need to use it all (and you can remove the parts you don't want), but it exists to provide developers a base to work off of.

I recommend ignoring the "simplest build.gradle" documentation (and don't go looking for another one). Instead, start looking at some sample Gradle build scripts and start trying to understand how they work and why they look the way they do. Focus on small pieces of a single script that you don't understand; don't try to take in the whole thing at once if you are finding entire scripts to be overwhelming.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio generate a structure for a multi-module gradle project (with one single module). There is a *main* `build.gradle` and a `settings.gradle` in the upper directory.

The buildscript definition can be found in this *main* `build.gradle` file.

`apply plugin: 'android'` is obselete and replaced by `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

The buildTypes comes with a default configuration for proguard (obfuscator) non active by default. (this is optional)

The dependencies section indicates that you can put any jar file in the libs dir (just as what you did with eclipse). If you don't have any jar in the libs dir : you can safely remove this part too.

If you don't specify it : minSdkVersion is 1